# Flickr api_sig (api signature)

Tags: api, digital-signature, flickr

pls help me with calculating **api_sig**. I have working URL request from here ([www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photosets.getP...](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photosets.getPhotos)).

I'm trying recalculate api_sig by myself. I'm generating md5 hash from this string:
"api_key071da8bd47cc06715f12e139
auth_token7215764931-65136290ea10d4b6
formatrest
methodflickr.photosets.getPhotosphoto
set_id7215924989144"

I don't know what should i use like [secret code]. Is it secret API key or is it "secret" from photoset? Or is it something else?

My string for md5 hash is:
"[secret]
api_key071da63edd47cc06715f12e139
auth_token757925931-65136290ea10d4b6
formatrestmethodflickr.photosets.getPhotos
photoset_id721746989144"

What am I doing wrong? I am getting different hash.

Thank you in advance for your advice and please excuse my English.

Comment: Sulution is here: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.howto.desktop.html

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the whitespaces from the string i.e. you should just generate a md5-string from this: "api_key071da8bd47cc06715f12e139auth_token7215764931-65136290ea10d4b6formatrestmethodflickr.photosets.getPhotosphotoset_id7215924989144". And then use that as the api_sig parameter.

Here are the steps: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.spec.html#signing